# Assigning Rails has_many_through with conditions, and keeping condirions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through

Given the following model

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships, class_name: "TeamMembership"
  has_many :members, -> { uniq(true) }, source: :user, through: :memberships
  has_many :owners,  -> { where('team_memberships.owner' => true) }, source: :user, through: :memberships
end
```

This works well enough (weird `uniq` syntax is because I'm on Rails 4), however in my specs:

```
describe Team do
  describe "users and owners" do
    fixtures :users
    subject     { create :team  }
    let(:bob)   { users  :bob   }
    let(:alice) { users  :alice }
    it "doesn't allow a member to be added more than once" do
      subject.members << bob
      subject.members.should include(bob)
      subject.members << bob
      subject.members.count.should == 1
    end
    it "doesn't allow an owner to be added more than once" do
      subject.owners << bob
      subject.owners.should include(bob)
      subject.owners << bob
      subject.owners.count.should == 1
    end
  end
end
```

You'll notice the second example "it doesn't allow an owner to be added more than once"  that I'm checking if `bob` has been correctly added to the owner list, he hasn't. He's in the `member` list, but his `TeamMembership` instance is lacking the `owner = true` flag.

I'm sure I've had this working in previous versions of Rails, but that's when it was a `conditions: { owner: true }` option on the relationship, not a lazy-evaluated lambda.

I am able to work around by doing:

```
subject.owners << bob
subject.members.should include(bob)
subject.memberships.find_by_user_id(bob.id).update_attribute(:owner, true)
```

This works well enough, but seems like a long way around. In short I want a way to to override `owners<<()` on the `Team` model, and run from there, but I'm not sure where to start. In the short term, my work around is sufficient, but I would have liked to have done it better.

How do I make `team.owners << bob` make his newly created membership set the `team_membership.owner = true` on assignment?